# Why Spanner performs full table scan using a underscore in a LIKE, while using % leverages the index?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

In a query, if I use `LIKE '<value>%'` on the primary key it performs well, using the index:

```
Operator | Rows returned | Executions | Latency
-- | -- | -- | --
 Serialize Result   32  1   1.80 ms
 Sort   32  1   1.78 ms
 Hash Aggregate 32  1   1.73 ms
 Distributed union  32  1   1.61 ms
 Hash Aggregate 32  1   1.56 ms
 Distributed union  128 1   1.34 ms
 Compute    -   -   -
 FilterScan 128 1   1.33 ms
 Table Scan: <tablename>    128 1   1.30 ms
```

Nevertheless, using `LIKE '<value>_'` performs a full table scan:

```
Operator | Rows returned | Executions | Latency
-- | -- | -- | --
Serialize Result | 32 | 1 | 76.27 s
Sort | 32 | 1 | 76.27 s
Hash Aggregate | 32 | 1 | 76.27 s
Distributed union | 32 | 1 | 76.27 s
Hash Aggregate | 32 | 2 | ~72.18 s
Distributed union | 128 | 2 | ~72.18 s
Compute | - | - | -
FilterScan | 128 | 2 | ~72.18 s
Table Scan: <tablename> (full scan: true) | 13802624 | 2 | ~69.97 s
```

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT
    'aggregated-quadkey AS quadkey' AS quadkey, day,
    SUM(a_value_1), SUM(a_value_2), AVG(a_value_3), SUM(a_value_4), SUM(a_value_5), AVG(a_value_6), AVG(a_value_6), AVG(a_value_7), SUM(a_value_8), SUM(a_value_9), AVG(a_value_10), SUM(a_value_11), SUM(a_value_12), AVG(a_value_13), AVG(a_value_14), AVG(a_value_15), SUM(a_value_16), SUM(a_value_17), AVG(a_value_18), SUM(a_value_19), SUM(a_value_20), AVG(a_value_21), AVG(a_value_22), AVG(a_value_23)
FROM <tablename>
WHERE quadkey LIKE '03201012212212322_'
GROUP BY quadkey, day ORDER BY day
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this! I have added this rewrite in the backlog. In the meantime, you can use STARTS_WITH and CHAR_LENGTH to work around the issue as RedPandaCurios suggested.

Comment: You can find some info on [answer] to upgrade your answer. It could be interesting to know how you came up with your answer.

Comment: yongchul works on Google Cloud Spanner (from his profile)

Answer (score 5):

For a prefix matching LIKE pattern (`column LIKE 'xxx%'`), the query optimiser internally converts the condition into `STARTS_WITH(column, 'xxx')`, which then uses the index.

So the reason is probably because the query optimizer is not smart enough to 
convert an exact length prefix matching LIKE pattern

```
column LIKE 'xxx_'
```

into a combined condition:

```
(STARTS_WITH(column, 'xxx') AND CHAR_LENGTH(column)=4)
```

Similarly, a pattern such as

```
`column LIKE 'abc%def'`
```

is not optimised into the combined condition:

```
`(STARTS_WITH(column,'abc') AND ENDS_WITH(column,'def'))`.
```

You can always work around this by optimising the query in your SQL generation by using the above condition.

(This is assuming that the LIKE pattern is a string value in the query, not a parameter - `LIKE` using a parameter cannot be optimised because the pattern is not known at query compile time.)

Comment: Yep, that's my assumption. I was just wondering if it's just an optimizer limitation or is there any intrinsic issue that I can't see (`_` is more restrictive than `%`, so it shouldn't perform worse at all).

PD: yes, the pattern is a value, not a parameter.